# Java: Excel/Json - How to read Json file and write to Excel

Tags: java, json, excel, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project wherein I have to read JSON file from folder and write it contents to Excel using Java. I'm new to this and gave a try.  But stuck at a point and unable to proceed. I was able to create a excel with header values set. but Unable to loop through JSON file and write in respective columns. Below is code to read JSON and creating excel and setting up headers.

```
public class SmartBusiness_TestResults extends Browser_Initilization {

public static void main(String[]args){

    System.out.println("Exports results");
    ExportResults();
}

public static void ExportResults () {
                try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
               JSONArray obj = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("./target/JSON/Output.json"));

               for(Object o: obj) {
                   JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) o;

                   String name = (String) jsonobj.get("id");
                   System.out.println(name);



                   String filename = "./target/JSON/Output.xls";
                   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                   HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  

                   HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
                   rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("SNO");
                   rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("name");
                   rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("ID");
                   rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Duration");
                   rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Status");
```

Kindly advice.

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Hint: this code writes many "header" that's strange.

Comment: @RC. this code writes only one header in excel.

Comment: No it does many times the "workbook creation + write row 0" because it's inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recipe:

- create the workbook
- create a sheet
- write headers
- loop over the json value and create a new row for each value
- output the workbook to a file